# Dimming image in Python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to implement dimming method to dim a image by converting pixel values and using this equation X(new) = 0.5 * X(old)^2. I did some googling and but could not succeed. Here is my code:

```
import math
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import color, io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def load(image_path):
    out = plt.imread(image_path)

    out = out.astype(np.float64) / 255
    return out


def dim_image(image):
    out = image.point(lambda x: x*0.5)

    return out

def display(img):
    # Show image
    plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

image1 = load(image1_path)
image2 = load(image2_path)

display(image1)
display(image2)

new_image = dim_image(image1)
display(new_image)
```

Comment: Where does it fail? Does it give errors or is the output not what you expected? Can you post an example image and the result? SO questions have to be specific or we can't really help, usually

Comment: I get this error on lambda x 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'point'

Comment: that makes more sense, i've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `.point` on a numpy array, which doesn't exist. I assume you meant to reduce all color values by 50% to dim the image, in which case you should use `np.dot` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)):

```
def dim_image(image):
    out = np.dot(image, 0.5)
    return out
```